# CakePHP update extra field on HABTM join table

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have problem with updating (better updating not recreating) extra field in HABTM join table. I searched google and other sources, but struggled for 4 days now.

I have models:

```
class Tutorial extends AppModel {
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'TutorialCategory' => array(
      'with' => 'TutorialCategoriesTutorial',
      'order' => 'TutorialCategoriesTutorial.order_by ASC',
      'unique' => true,
  );
}

class TutorialCategory extends AppModel {
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tutorial' => array(
      'with' => 'TutorialCategoriesTutorial',
      'unique' => true,
  );
}
```

join table tutorial_categories_tutorial have id, tutorial_id, tutorial_category_id, order_by fields.

I am trying to update order_by field like:

```
$order = 1;
foreach($tutorials as $i => $tutorial) {
  $this->data[$i]['Tutorial']['id'] = $tutorial['Tutorial']['id];
  $this->data[$i]['TutorialCategory']['id'] = $tutorial['TutorialCategory']['id];
  $this->data[$i]['TutorialCategoriesTutorial']['order_by'] = $order;

  ++$order;
}
$this->Tutorial->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('TutorialCategoriesTutorial')));
$saved = $this->Tutorial->saveAll($this->data);
```

This is deleting and crating new records in join table, but not setting order_by at all. I want to update record and set now order_by value. I tried hasMany through but no luck.

Please help and/or give advice and explanation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As you have added extra data (order field) to the HABTM join model, you have actually exceeded the capabilities of a simple HABTM relationship with CakePHP. What you actually need to setup is a [hasMany Through relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

In your case you'll basically make a "membership" model with Tutorial ID, catergory id and as much data as you want to assign to it. You will then define the relatioships as Membership belongsTo Tutorial & Category. The book probably has a better example than what I've just explained!

The main reason for this is that each "membership" record is treated as a normal record with no HABTM behaviour attached to it, so you can edit, delete and add records individually and easily.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. I made model TutorialCategoriesTutorial and set belongsTo Tutorial (has many TutorialCategoriesTutorial) and TutorialCategory (has many TutorialCategoriesTutorial). But no luck with that. Because I can not realize how to form the $this->data to update these fields. Can you give me example, please?

Comment: You just save it as you would any other model, eg: `$this->data['TutorialCategoryTutorial']['tutorial_id']` and use `$this->TutorialCategoryTutorial->save()`

Comment: Ok, I will try it a little bit later (now I changed my task). But it will update or delete/insert new values? In my join table is id primary_key - it will not affect? Thanks

Comment: It will act just like any other model, if you include the ID it will edit a row, if you want a new one you call create() first.