# CakePHP HABTM JoinTable w/Extra Field

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I have a customers table, a contacts table, and a contacts_customers join table, which also has contact_type_id field which maps to a contact_type table. I have used the information linked to from [CakePHP update extra field on HABTM join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677602/cakephp-update-extra-field-on-habtm-join-table) in an attempt to come up with a solution, but it's only partly working. I changed the `add()` method in the `ContactCustomersController` to

```
$this->ContactsCustomer->Contact->save($this->data);
$this->ContactsCustomer->create();
if ($this->ContactsCustomer->save($this->data,
   array('validate' => 'first'))) {
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contacts customer has been saved', true));
   $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'contacts_customers', 'action' => 'index'));
} else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contacts customer could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
}
```

Note the two-part save; this is because using the `saveAll()` method of the `ContactsCustomer` model was just out and out failing with no indication of the problem (all that showed up in the SQL log on the resulting page was a `BEGIN` immediately followed by a `ROLLBACK`). My assumption here was that this was due to the foreign key constraint between the `contacts` table and the `contacts_customers` table, so I opted for the two-part save.

In any event, there are no errors reported in the current code, but the end result is that the appropriate information is saved in the `contacts` table, but nothing is saved in the `contacts_customers` join table. The data posted appears to be appropriate according to the FireBug log data:

```
_method POST
data[Contact][address_1]    asdsad
data[Contact][address_2]    
data[Contact][city] asdasd 
data[Contact][email]    jb@sc.net
data[Contact][fax]  
data[Contact][first_name]   Joe
data[Contact][last_name]    Blow
data[Contact][mobile_phon...    
data[Contact][office_phon...    sdfsdfdf
data[Contact][postal_code...    121212
data[Contact][state]    asdas
data[Contact][title]    
data[ContactsCustomer][ContactType] 
data[ContactsCustomer][ContactType][]   1
data[ContactsCustomer][ContactType][]   2
data[ContactsCustomer][ContactType][]   3
data[ContactsCustomer][Customer]    1
```

What have I done incorrectly here? Many thanks to any assistance offered!

Relevant model data:

contact.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'ContactsCustomer'
);
```

contact_types.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'ContactsCustomer'
);
```

customer.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'ContactsCustomer'
);
```

contacts_customer.php

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Contact', 'ContactType', 'Customer'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested that yet, but I believe $this->data might have been modified by the first save. Just use an extra variable to hold that data.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but there doesn't appear to be any change of note in the contents of `$this->data`, including its subarrays.

I am still investigating multiple avenues.